# Does azure pipelines support variable interpolation?

Tags: environment-variables, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create an environment variable that represents the build version in the format `x.y` where

- `x` is some fixed value and
- `y` is incremented by azure per build

I've tried creating a variable that is a concatenation of fixed value and Azure's built-in variable `Build.BuildId` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)):

`1.${Build.BuildId}`

[image]

I was hoping it would get extrapolated into e.g. `1.1` but when I ran the pipeline it failed on docker push with the following error:

`Error parsing reference: "private.registry.com/app:1.${Build.BuildId}" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format`

so clearly the extrapolation did not work. Any ideas how to properly reference `Build.BuildId` inside the variable definition?

Comment: ok, why dont you use proper syntax? `$(%name%)`?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work either: 
```Error parsing reference: "private.registry.com/app:1.$(%Build.BuildId%)" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format```

Comment: without `%` it was just an example so you understand its a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap the predefined variable in `$()` not `${}` in your environment variable definition.

```
BUILD_NUMBER = 1.$(Build.BuildId)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  Do you have a reference to the official docs?

Comment: This is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) i found about how to work with variables in pipeline.